# Create a new HTML page based on PHP loop

Tags: php, html, sql

As you can see `$x` passes inside the SQL query. I want to increment `$x++` as many times needed and each time create a new *.html* page for each different `$result`. How is this possible?

```
    $x = 1;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `persons` WHERE CODE_NO = '$x'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    }

$table = "<table>"; // table tag in HTML


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
//Creates a loop to loop through results
$table .= "<tr>";
$table .= "<th>CODE_NO:</th>";
$table .= "<td>" . $row['CODE_NO'] . "</td>";
$table .= "</tr>";
$table .= "<tr>";
$table .= "<th>FIRST_NAME:</th>";
$table .= "<td>" . $row['FIRST_NAME'] . "</td>";
$table .= "</tr>";
$table .= "<tr>";
$table .= "<th>SURNAME:</th>";
$table .= "<td>" . $row['SURNAME'] . "</td>";
$table .= "</tr>";
$table .= "<tr>";
$table .= "<th>Date of birth:</th>";
$table .= "<td>" . $row['DOB'] . "</td>";
$table .= "</tr>";
$table .= "<tr>";
$table .= "<th>Date of death:</th>";
$table .= "<td> " . $row['DOD'] . "</td>";
$table .= "</tr>";
}
$table .= "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

echo $table;

?>
```

Comment: So the code you provided has basically nothing to do with what you're asking, or am I mistaken?

Comment: what you think about while(true){//loop}

Comment: @JulienLachal I guess you are not. I've made some attemps to solve the problem without success, so I posted a working piece of code.

Comment: Do you *really* want to create a new *.html* file for each one or do you actually want that code to appear at an URL like `{$x}.html` ?

Comment: _"many times needed"_ What is this need? An arbitrary number or number of records from a database table?

Comment: Then show these "attempts at solving the problem" instead of this piece of code, and we'll be able to guide you.

Comment: @CD001 I guess the later will do as well.

Comment: @kapelnick - the latter is the *normal* way to do it; most MVC frameworks are based around a single *index.php* file which has *most* URLs routed through it and *it* determines what to do with them... but this goes way beyond the scope of what can realistically be answered on SO (in a single question at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update the query to pull all code numbers in one query ( Sorted by CODE_NO ).

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `persons` WHERE CODE_NO > 0 ORDER BY CODE_NO;";
```

You should index CODE_NO for optimization.

```
    <?php

$rows = [
    ['CODE_NO'=>1,'FIRST_NAME'=>1,'SUR_NAME'=>1,'DOB'=>1,'DOD'=>1],
    ['CODE_NO'=>1,'FIRST_NAME'=>2,'SUR_NAME'=>2,'DOB'=>2,'DOD'=>2],
    ['CODE_NO'=>3,'FIRST_NAME'=>1,'SUR_NAME'=>1,'DOB'=>1,'DOD'=>3],
    ['CODE_NO'=>4,'FIRST_NAME'=>1,'SUR_NAME'=>1,'DOB'=>1,'DOD'=>4],
    ['CODE_NO'=>5,'FIRST_NAME'=>1,'SUR_NAME'=>1,'DOB'=>1,'DOD'=>5],
];
    $index =1;
    $codes=[];
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $codes[$row['CODE_NO']][] =$row;
    }
    foreach($codes as $tableArray){
        $table = "<table>".PHP_EOL;
        $is_titles = true;
        foreach($tableArray as $rowArray){

            if($is_titles){
                $is_titles = false;
                $table .= "<tr>".PHP_EOL;
                foreach($rowArray as $key => $value){
                    $table .= "<th>".$key."</th>".PHP_EOL;
                }    
                $table .= "</tr>".PHP_EOL;
            }
            $table .= "<tr>".PHP_EOL;
                foreach($rowArray as $key => $value){
                    $table .= "<td>" . $value . "</td>".PHP_EOL;
                }    
                $table .= "</tr>".PHP_EOL;


        }


        $table .= "</table>".PHP_EOL;
        echo $table;
        }



?>
```

In my code i printed each CODE_NO value in different table but you can create a new file and put table content if you need.

`$rows` is my mock, you should replace it with real data.

OUTPUT:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>CODE_NO</th>
<th>FIRST_NAME</th>
<th>SUR_NAME</th>
<th>DOB</th>
<th>DOD</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<th>CODE_NO</th>
<th>FIRST_NAME</th>
<th>SUR_NAME</th>
<th>DOB</th>
<th>DOD</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<th>CODE_NO</th>
<th>FIRST_NAME</th>
<th>SUR_NAME</th>
<th>DOB</th>
<th>DOD</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<th>CODE_NO</th>
<th>FIRST_NAME</th>
<th>SUR_NAME</th>
<th>DOB</th>
<th>DOD</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code works but at the end only one table gets printed. I want each time the loop runs to print a different table. How to do that?

Comment: How many unique `CODE_NO` you have ? as you can see, every time that `CODE_NO` updating, table will printed.

Comment: I have 12.000 unique CODE_NO. It only prints ONE table, that with CODE_NO=12.000. I want to print all of them.